# Changing UPN to a Mail Id

Tags: azure-active-directory, o365-flow, upn

By default all the User Principle Name and mail for O365  will be same but how to change User Principle Name and also how can we create  an user with different User Principle Name and different mail.

Answer (score 0):

**To change the User Principal Name, execute the following command,**

```
Set-MsolUserPrincipalName -UserPrincipalName "davidc@contoso.com" -NewUserPrincipalName "davidchew@contoso.com"
```

The *****[Set-MsolUserPrincipalName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/set-msoluserprincipalname?view=azureadps-1.0)***** cmdlet changes the User Principal Name, or user ID, of a user.

> It is not recommended to use different UPN and Mail-id due to the below reasons:

- User confusion
- Skype for Business Online
- Office ProPlus
- Mobile Applications
- ActiveSync

To know more in detail please **refer** these links,

[Ref1](https://support.cloudhq.net/it-admin-office-365-why-your-user-principal-name-upn-should-match-your-email-address/), [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56472220/how-to-change-user-principal-name-on-azure-ad).